# I want to merge multiple records into a single record in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to merge multiple records into a single record in BigQuery

```
pdt status            dt      
a   Inctive         2022/02/07
a   Inctive         2022/02/08
a   Active          2022/02/10  
a   Active          2022/02/11
a   Active          2022/02/15  
a   Active          2022/02/16
a   Active          2022/02/17
b   Active          2022/03/13  
b   Active          2022/03/14

Output

pdt status          start_dt    end_dt
a   Inactive        2022/02/07  2022/02/08
a   Active          2022/02/10  2022/02/11
a   Active          2022/02/15  2022/02/17
b   Active          2022/03/13  2022/03/14
```

I want to know how implement normalize on period function in bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
SELECT pdt, status, MIN(dt) AS start_dt, MAX(dt) AS end_dt FROM (
  SELECT *, UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', dt)) - COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY pdt ORDER BY dt) AS part
    FROM sample_data
) GROUP BY pdt, status, part
-- ORDER BY 1, 3;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: is it possible to achieve with single column of date?

Comment: @KMH,  I've updated the answer. kindly check that out

Comment: small refactoring :o) - you can omit use of UNIX_DATE and just use `PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', dt) - COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY pdt ORDER BY dt) AS part`

Comment: @Jaytiger Thanks a lot for your help. It worked. I have another question similar to this. Could you please help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936784/i-want-to-merge-multiple-records-into-a-single-record-in-bigquery