# I want to merge multiple records into a single record in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Input

| pdt | amount | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.5 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-07 |
| a | 2.2 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-08 |
| a | 0.5 | 2022-01-09 | 2022-01-10 |
| a | 0.5 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-14 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-18 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-19 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-28 |

Expected Output

| pdt | amount | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.5 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-07 |
| a | 2.2 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-08 |
| a | 0.5 | 2022-01-09 | 2022-01-14 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-19 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-28 |

Query which I am trying

```sql
SELECT pdt, amount, MIN(start_dt) start_dt, MAX(end_dt) end_dt FROM (
  SELECT *, dt - COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY pdt ORDER BY start_dt) AS part
    FROM table, UNNEST (GENERATE_ARRAY(
      UNIX_DATE(start_dt), UNIX_DATE(end_dt))
    ) AS dt
) GROUP BY pdt, amount, part
```

Output I am getting

| pdt | amount | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.5 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-14 |
| a | 2.2 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-08 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-19 |
| b | 1.5 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-28 |

Comment: On what basis do you want to merge the records? @KMH

Comment: If product and amount matches and there is no gap between end date and next record start date then it should merge

Comment: @KMH I answered.

Comment: If there is overlap between end date and next record start date then how it should be? Ex:

Comment: It is not working as expected if there is overlap between end date and next record start date. Could you please help with this? Ex:  
pdt amount start_dt end_dt
a 0.5 2022-01-05 2022-01-07
a 2.2 2022-01-08 2022-01-08
a 0.5 2022-01-09 2022-01-11
a 0.5 2022-01-11 2022-01-14
b 1.5 2022-01-15 2022-01-19
b 1.5 2022-01-19 2022-01-19
b 1.5 2022-01-25 2022-01-28

Expected output
pdt amount start_dt end_dt
a 0.5 2022-01-05 2022-01-07
a 2.2 2022-01-08 2022-01-08
a 0.5 2022-01-09 2022-01-14
b 1.5 2022-01-15 2022-01-19
b 1.5 2022-01-25 2022-01-28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below.

> If product and amount matches and there is no gap between end date and next record start date then it should merge

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'a' pdt, 0.5 amount, DATE '2022-01-05' start_dt, DATE '2022-01-07' end_dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' pdt, 2.2 amount, '2022-01-08' start_dt, '2022-01-08' end_dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' pdt, 0.5 amount, '2022-01-09' start_dt, '2022-01-10' end_dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' pdt, 0.5 amount, '2022-01-11' start_dt, '2022-01-14' end_dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' pdt, 1.5 amount, '2022-01-15' start_dt, '2022-01-18' end_dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' pdt, 1.5 amount, '2022-01-19' start_dt, '2022-01-19' end_dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' pdt, 1.5 amount, '2022-01-25' start_dt, '2022-01-28' end_dt
)
SELECT pdt, amount, MIN(dt) start_dt, MAX(dt) end_dt
  FROM (
  SELECT *, dt - COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY pdt, '' || amount ORDER BY dt) AS part
    FROM sample_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_dt, end_dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) dt
) GROUP BY pdt, amount, part;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that this script worked at BigQuery sandbox mode.
You can use it for free.

```sql
WITH TB AS(
 SELECT
  pdt,
  amount,
  start_dt,
  end_dt, 
  LAG(end_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(pdt as STRING),CAST(amount as STRING) ORDER BY start_dt) AS pre_end_dt,
  LEAD(start_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(pdt as STRING),CAST(amount as STRING) ORDER BY start_dt) AS next_start_dt
 FROM `your_project_id.stackoverflow.mytable`
 ORDER BY pdt, start_dt
)
, C AS (
 SELECT 
  TB.*
 ,CASE WHEN TB.pre_end_dt + 1 <> TB.start_dt THEN 1
       WHEN TB.pre_end_dt + 1 = TB.start_dt THEN 0
       WHEN TB.pre_end_dt IS NULL THEN 1
       END AS start_dif
 ,CASE WHEN TB.next_start_dt - 1 <> TB.end_dt THEN 1
       WHEN TB.next_start_dt - 1 = TB.end_dt THEN 0
       WHEN TB.next_start_dt IS NULL THEN 1
       END AS end_dif
 FROM TB
)
, R AS (
 SELECT
  C.*
  ,CASE WHEN C.start_dif = 1 AND C.end_dif = 0 THEN  LEAD(C.end_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY C.pdt ORDER BY C.start_dt)
       WHEN C.start_dif = 1 AND C.end_dif = 1 THEN  C.end_dt
       WHEN C.start_dif = 0 AND C.end_dif = 1 THEN  NULL
       END AS new_end_dt
 FROM C
 WHERE C.start_dif = 1 OR C.end_dif = 1
)

SELECT 
  R.pdt,
  R.amount,
  R.start_dt,
  R.new_end_dt AS end_dt  
 FROM R
 WHERE R.new_end_dt IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY R.pdt, R.start_dt
```

[image]

### Reference

- [「開始日付」と「終了日付」で管理しているデータをSQLで期間集約するには?](https://qiita.com/toronya/items/8fdd99717b78ccb0bdd2)